# Is it possible to use Amazon Simple mail system (Amazon SES) in my own application on a GoDaddy hosting plan?

Tags: php, email, amazon-ses

In one of my web application in PHP I likes to integrate Amazon Mail system . When user completed the registration process I wanna send a mail and also weekly news letters and all ... Is it possible with Amazon mail service ? I am using GoDaddy hosting plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use: From: [Release: AWS SDK for PHP 1.2.3](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/PHP/2186402446547287)

> Release: AWS SDK for PHP 1.2.3
>
> This release adds support for Amazon Simple Email Service.

The following sample demonstrates how to send an email:

```
$email = new AmazonSES();

$response = $email->send_email(
    'no-reply@amazon.com', // Source (aka From)
    array('ToAddresses' => 'nobody@amazon.com'), // Destination (aka To)
    array( // Message (short form)
        'Subject.Data' => 'Email Test',
        'Body.Text.Data' => 'This is a simple test message ' . time()
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks for the code .. Thanks .. I will go through it and will get back you if any prob .. Thanks again ...

Comment: @rajeeesh visit the link above. You will find more info like `Known Issues`